# @HtmlActionLink can it be applied to this situation or do I need to use somthing else?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an ActionResult Details()

```
// RETREIVE THE INDIVIDUAL DETAILS SHOWS
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        var item = from s in db.Shows.Where(si => si.ShowId == id) select s;

        return View(item);
    }
}
```

The updated ul is now the following:

```
<div id = "browseShow">  <ul>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li class = "lihead">
    @item.Title
    </li>
    <li class = "lihead">
    @item.Director.Name
    @Html.ActionLink((string)item.Director.Name, "Index" "Director", new { director = item.Director.Name }, null)
    </li>
    <li>
    <i>@item.Synopsis</i>
    </li> 
    <li class = "lihead">
    Price per ticket £
    @item.Price
    </li>        
}
```

I have updated the index method to receive a string:

```
  public ActionResult Index(string director)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: The director name is showing up as an HTML attribute, and not on the query string, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong overload for `Html.ActionLink`

Try this one

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Director.Name.ToString(), "Index", "Director", new { director = item.Director.Name }, null)
```

Right now you're passing in the RouteValues as the HtmlAttributes. The extra null at the end will call the correct one.

The original post was deleted, but you are also passing in the director name under the `director` property, but your method is receiving an `int id`. You'll need to fix that as well.

Comment: I have tried the ActionLink with the null and that does not work, I now have 14 errors the first is referring to the use of html helpers :Error 1 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' has no applicable method named 'ActionLink' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

Comment: @Spangle, does Direct.Name have a type or is a dynamic type? Try casting it as a string. `(string)item.Director.Name`

Comment: Following (string)item.Director.Name has removed some of the errors, the next error is telling me that I should close an open bracket ) after "Director" and that i I should insert a ; but this would end the line earlier that it should be. The last time I cast to a string I did it slightly different item.Director.Name.toString()

Comment: @Spangle, then you have a syntax error. Update the question with your revised code. Either method of casting should work fine.

Comment: @Spangle, Whoops, sorry. Your original example was missing a comma between Index and Director and I didn't notice it, so I carried it over in my example. Just add it back in.